# How to add a blank new row to WPF DataGrid automatically when user start editing current row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bind with `ObservableCollection<MydataObject> MyDatalist` With all the default settings, if user change the focus from the `DataGrid` (e.g. clicked a `button`) while editing a cell, all the data showing in the `DataGrid` includes the one the user is editing are stored to `MyDatalist`, this is great, but the user need to hit "Tab" (while in the last cell) or "Enter" to create a new row.

I want the DataGrid to generate a new row automatically when user start editing any cell of the last row. I have tried the `CurrentCellChanged` event and I can have the new row automatically created by doing this:

```
void dataGrid1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dataGrid1.CommitEdit(); 
}
```

However, with this implemented, if user change the focus from the `DataGrid` (e.g. clicked a `button`) while editing a cell, the one that the user is editing is not stored to `MyDatalist`, How can I have this feature back with the new row automatically added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is a [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) set this solved my problem:

`Binding="{Binding Path=field1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: This answer could use a larger example showing the entire DataGrids xaml.